# Thycotic Secret Server APIS access

Tags: vault

I want to access Thycotic Secret Server  Rest APIS,But when I try to authenticate and get token,I am getting html response,instead of token?Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this is very late, but I have a base auth script that I use and just craft my API call around. Hope it helps. Below is an example of a GET request for a secret

```
try {
    $site = "https://company.secretservercloud.com"
    $creds = @{
        username   = "user1"
        password   = "password1"
        grant_type = "password"
    }

    $response = Invoke-RestMethod "$site/oauth2/token" -Method Post -Body $creds 
    $token = $response.access_token
    
    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer $token")
    #======================================
    #=======PASTE POWERSHELL HERE=========
    #=====================================
    $response = Invoke-RestMethod $site'/api/v1/secrets/1662' -Method 'GET' -Headers $headers
    $response = $response | ConvertTo-Json
    write-host $response
    #======================================
    #=======PASTE POWERSHELL HERE=========
    #=====================================
}
catch [System.Net.WebException] {
    Write-Host "----- Exception -----"
    Write-Host  $_.Exception
    Write-Host  $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
    Write-Host  $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
    $result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
    $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
    $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
    $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
    $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd()

    Write-Host $responseBody
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you're hitting the wrong url/api end. remove 'SecretServer' from the uri and try again. so the uri should look below:

"https://COMPANY_NAME.secretservercloud.com/oauth2/token"

if it helps, you can also use the below powershell script to get the token.

function Get-ThycoticToken
{

```
[cmdletbinding()]   
Param (     
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Position=0)]
    [System.String]$BaseUrl,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Position=1)]
    [System.String]$UserName,

    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Position=1)]
    [System.String]$Password
)


$OauthApi = "$BaseUrl/oauth2/token"




$payload = @{
"Accept" = "application/json"
"username" = $UserName
"password" = $Password
"grant_type" = "password"
}


$response = Invoke-RestMethod $OauthApi -Method Post -Body $payload


$token = $response.access_token

$token
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I tried the solution provided and convert it to powershell for more better response

Please find below script you can use to get token from an api using powershell

```
[cmdletbinding()]   
Param (     
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, 
Position=0)]
[System.String]$BaseUrl,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, 
Position=1)]
[System.String]$UserName,

[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true, 
Position=2)]
[System.String]$Password
)

$OauthApi = "$BaseUrl/oauth2/token"

$payload = @{
"Accept"     = "application/json"
"username"   = $UserName
"password"   = $Password
"grant_type" = "password"
 }

 try {
 $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $OauthApi -Method Post -Body $payload

 if ($response.access_token) {
    $token = $response.access_token
    Write-Output "Access Token: $token"
 } else {
    Write-Host "Failed to obtain access token. Check credentials and try 
again."
}
}
catch [System.Net.WebException] {
Write-Host "----- Exception -----"
Write-Host $_.Exception
Write-Host $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode
Write-Host $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
$result = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
$reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($result)
$reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
$reader.DiscardBufferedData()
$responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd()

Write-Host $responseBody
}
```